# How to export chunk in http.request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

This http.request code is from http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/http.html#http.request.
How to export **chunk** in res.on ?

```
  var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: What do you mean with "export" ?

Comment: I try using "exports.chunk = chunk" but it isn't work.

Comment: You understand the chunk wouldn't be immediately available but only when google answered (so at an undefined time after your program startup) ?

Comment: How can I do? I want to use chunk from this js file

Comment: You shouldn't try to export chunk but to export a function taking a callback as parameter, callback to which your function would pass the chunk. You also should concatenate the chunks, you have no guarantee that the whole answer is in one chunk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "export" but perhaps you'd like to put the contents of the response into a local text file?

Here's how you might go about doing that:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    var response;
    if(fs.existsSync('response.html'))
      response = fs.readFileSync('response.html') + chunk;
    else
      response = chunk;
    fs.writeFileSync('response.html', response);
  });
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Note that after each `data` event is fired, we're checking for an existing file with `fs.existsSync`, populating a response variable accordingly and then writing the response to a file again with `fs.writeFileSync`.

This wouldn't be much use on a server, as the synchronous nature of the file reads/writes would bottleneck your traffic, but it does highlight the general concept of responding to events and concatenating chunks.